# UFT unable to identify objects in Chrome even after enabling the extension

Tags: hp-uft

All of a sudden UFT tool stopped identifying objects in Chrome all the objects get identified as Win object. I have my UFT extension enabled.

Answer (score 0):

See the below comment from user Phenomite in the MicroFocus forums - It seems Chrome released a silent patch which messed things up for UFT/LeanFT(UFT Pro):

This is caused by a silent patch that has rolled out to address fullscreen and popup sandboxing issues with extensions using gesture APIs. A chromium forum engineer posted the changed code which directed me in how to fix it.

-> Open chrome://flags.

-> Search for "Touch events API" and set it to "Enabled"

-> Search for "User Activation V2" and set it to "Enabled"

-> Click the restart chrome prompt.

If you are interested, the patch code that fixed (but broke) extension gestures API: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/6b20212bdffccd581703de1f229921151ea4750b/extensions/renderer/bindings/api_request_handler.cc#264

Source: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing-User/UFT-14-03-Build-3501-not-recognizing-Google-Chrome-71-0-3578-98/m-p/1681220